Using WPS office after upgrade to 24.04 creates ghost icons
After the upgrade I have noticed that dragging a file to WPS office window in order to open it leaves behind a ghost icon stuck on the screen above all windows:
Ghost icon:

Using nautilus -q solves the problem, but it is generally annoying and I have no clue how to debug this behavior.

I have encountered a similar issue when I drag and drop an image from Files (Nautilus) into Writer. The ghost icon sometimes disappears after I drag the image and move its position within the document.
I have submitted a bug report to WPS.
